# Open JSON File without downloading it

Tags: android, json, download, permissions

For my Android App i am using JSON Files, which i am downloading on the storage. For that i have to set several permissions.

Is there a way to "download" files without any permission. Open them, getting the input from the file and work with it

Comment: The problem here is that you are accessing files, and for that you need READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions. Why are you downloading JSON Files? Is it a response from a server or something?

Answer (score 1):

Place your JSON file inside the assests folder and then you can read the data from the file using below function:

```
public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
String json = null;
try {
    InputStream is = getActivity().getAssets().open("yourfilename.json");
    int size = is.available();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    is.read(buffer);
    is.close();
    json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
return json;
}
```

For more details on parsing data from JSON, visit [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidJSON/article.html) link.

Comment: He is trying to access the file from within the app, not from the assets inside the project.

Comment: Thats a good solution but the problem is, the JSON file is from a server, so i can't store it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Only Internet Permission in your Menifest to download the file form internet.

```
///<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


  new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                super.run();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://yourwebpage.com/abc.json");
                    // Read all the text returned by the server
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                    String str;
                    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(str);
                    }
                    in.close();
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }

                String your_json=sb.toString();

                //process Json Here



            }
        }.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with Android 4.4 (API level 19), reading or writing files in your app's private external storage directory—accessed using getExternalFilesDir()—does not require the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions. So if your app supports Android 4.3 (API level 18) and lower, and you want to access only the private external storage directory, you should declare that the permission be requested only on the lower versions of Android by adding the maxSdkVersion attribute:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
                     android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

For more info please refer https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#PrivateFiles